# Django Tastypie POST Unauthorized on different servers

Tags: python, django, oauth, oauth-2.0, tastypie

I have set up OAuth 2.0 as described by Ian Alexander using tastypie, django-oauth2-provider, and
https://github.com/ianalexander/django-oauth2-tastypie/blob/master/src/authentication.py

This works splendidly on my local server

```
class AllowGetAuthentication(OAuth20Authentication):
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        """ If GET, don't check auth, otherwise fall back to parent """
        if request.method == "GET":
            return True
        else:
            return super(AllowGetAuthentication, self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)

class BaseModelResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = AllowGetAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

When running this on our hosted development server, however, all POSTs come back HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED

I've attempted the following tests to no avail:

(1) replace

```
DjangoAuthorization()
```

with

```
Authorization()
```

(2) replace

```
return super(AllowGetAuthentication, self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)
```

with

```
return True
```

(3) create a wrapper for all the api urls that is csrf exempt

The only things that has worked was to implement #1 and #2 at the same time (ie bypass authentication AND authorization) which seems to indicate it's not just a deny all at the webserver level.

Any thoughts here are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an apache issue
Add this line to your site conf file

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

[Where do I put "WSGIPassAuthorization On"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780966/where-do-i-put-wsgipassauthorization-on)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have not enabled cors.

```
class BaseModelResource(ModelResource):
     class Meta:
        queryset = BaseModel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'api'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = OAuth20Authentication()
```

Also in production or on any server: You need to add corsheaders to access it from other domains.

Use this [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)

Steps to use that :

1. pip install django-cors-headers
2. add 'corsheaders' in INSTALLED_APPS
3. add 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware' in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
4. add CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True in settings.py

P.S. : You can change the settings later after reading about cors to make it secure.

Comment: Implemented your suggestion, but still Unauthorized :(

Comment: Paste your request print trace in resource